# data = request.get_json(force=True) UnboundLocalError: local variable 'request' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-requests, request

I'm facing `request` variable error here
**File "C:\Users\ayush\Python\iris_server.py", line 10, in predict
data = request.get_json(force=True)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'request' referenced before assignment**
when I run my client side code which has hardcoded values of the data fields

Flask Server side:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import numpy as np
import pickle
import os
os.chdir('C:/Users/ayush/Python')
model = pickle.load(open('iris_model','rb')) 
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/api',methods=['POST'])  
def predict():     
    data = request.get_json(force=True)     
    predict_request=[[data['sepal_length'],data['sepal_width'],data['petal_length'],data['petal_width']]]     
    request=np.array(predict_request)    
    print(request)     
    prediction = model.predict(predict_request)     
    pred = prediction[0]     
    print(pred)     
    return jsonify(int(pred))
    
if __name__ == '__main__':          
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

Client side

```
import requests
import json
r = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/api', json={"sepal_lenth":3.2,
    "sepal_width":7.3,
    "petal_length":4.5,
    "petal_width":2.1})
r.status_code
print(r)
```

while the client side gives **<Response [500]>** as the output
so assuming the code isn't the problem here,
How can I fix this
Thanks in Advance

Comment: you have imported `request` from `Flask` and there is also an object created with the same name: `request=np.array(predict_request)`, change the object name to something else.

Comment: You are using request variable `request=np.array(predict_request)`, that's why python thinks `request` in `request.get_json(force=True)` is a variable not `flask.request`, just change variable request to something else

Comment: you could also `from flask import request as flask_request` to avoid confusion

Comment: Thanks @KrishnaChaurasia Elbek and c8999c You were it fixed that error, but now I ran into another

Comment: I ran into another error: return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\bhosl\Python\iris_server.py", line 11, in predict
    predict_request=[[data["sepal_length"],data["sepal_width"],data["petal_length"],data["petal_width"]]]
KeyError: 'sepal_length'